# Is it a correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I am writing an statement of purpose. There I would like to say the following thing.

"In my M.Sc., I worked with Professor X who I later joined as a PhD student."

Is it correct grammatically?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please note that this is neither a writers workshop nor a proofreading service, as such requests are rarely helpful as references and are ill-suited to our Q&A format. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Which part of your statement do you think might be incorrect? Without adding a specific concern, your question would be considered proofreading, which is off-topic.

Comment: I had a confusion about "whom" and "who". Also I was not sure if I should write "with whom" or "to whom".

Answer (score 2):

Almost right. In the second clause, you are saying "I joined Professor X", so Professor X is the object of the second clause. You therefore have to use the object form of who, which is whom.

```
In my MSc, I worked with Professor X **whom** I later joined as a PhD student.
```

As a side note, it's OK to write M.Sc. and Ph.D. with or without full stops (without is rather less formal) but you should be consistent.

Comment: To be more precise: many people do not use _whom_ at all, and would have no problem with what you wrote. Some people use it only in a formal context: since this is a relatively formal context, I would recomment you use _whom_.